Searching Users in a B2C Tenant using a C# Application
Sorry to bother once again but I am trying to implement a search by Email Address in the application using the same logic as the viewing users function that was fixed wonderfully for me yesterday (.Request() not working in C# with an Azure AD B2C) but it just does not seem to work the same way. I have most likely done it wrong but I need a hand because I can't seem to find the answer on Microsoft Learn and ChatGPT is working off data too old to know that .Request() has been evicted from Graph.
I have tried this function -
    public static async Task SearchUsers()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "...";
    var clientId = "...";
    var clientSecret = "...";

    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    Console.Write("Enter user email address: ");
    string emailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"Looking for user with email address '{emailAddress}'...");

    try
    {
        var users = await graphClient.Users
            .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "givenName", "surname", "businessPhones", "identities" };
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{emailAddress}' and c/signInType eq 'emailAddress')";
            });

        if (users != null && users.Value.Any())
        {
            var user = users.Value.FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {user.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Email: {emailAddress}");


                // Check if business phone numbers are available
                if (user.BusinessPhones != null && user.BusinessPhones.Any())
                {
                    Console.Write("Business Phones: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", user.BusinessPhones));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Business Phones: N/A");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No user found with the provided email address.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No user found with the provided email address.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

For reference, this is the ListUsers() function I am basing it off -
`public static async Task ListUsers()
{
Console.WriteLine("Getting list of users...");
   var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
   var tenantId = "...";
   var clientId = "...";
   var clientSecret = "...";

   ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
   var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

   try
   {
       var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
       {
           requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id", "displayName", "GivenName", "Surname", "BusinessPhones", "Identities"};
       });

       foreach (var user in users.Value)
       {
           // Extract email address from identities
           var emailAddress = user.Identities?.FirstOrDefault(i => i.SignInType == "emailAddress")?.IssuerAssignedId;

           // Skip user if no email address is found
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
               continue;

           Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
           Console.WriteLine($"ID: {user.Id}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Email: {emailAddress}");
           

           // Check if business phone numbers are available
           if (user.BusinessPhones != null && user.BusinessPhones.Any())
           {
               Console.Write("Business Phones: ");
               Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", user.BusinessPhones));
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Business Phones: N/A");
           }

           Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Error listing users: {ex.Message}");
   }


^ I've edited the above code with a solution that has no serious errors but still does not fetch any data.

Does this work for you. Check this

tried it but the email is the identity, as shown in the above ListUsers() code

Can you brief your requirement?

need a search function based on the users identity which is an email address a shown here https://imgur.com/a/nozHet0

Sure will be posting the answer

To search or fetch users by their email address/users identity, modify the code like below:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

static async Task SearchUsers()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "TenantID";
    var clientId = "ClientID";
    var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
    
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    try
    {
        var result = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName", "identities", "GivenName", "Surname", "Mail" };
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'xxx@outlook.com' and c/issuer eq 'xxx@outlook.com')";
        });

        if (result.Value != null && result.Value.Any())
        {
            foreach (var user in result.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Email: {user.Mail}");
                                              
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No users found with the specified criteria.");
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"Graph API Error: {ex.Message}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

await SearchUsers();

I am able to fetch the details successfully by passing the email address/users identity:


Glas that it worked:)

In general now, can the same logic be used in a WinForms as opposed to console?

Yes it can be used
